# What is the practice in REST to name getting a resource by another resource ID

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, restful-url, entities

I'm creating a RESTful weather by cities service, i.e. a client knows a city ID and wants to receive a weather report in JSON from this city. For example:

```
{temperature:xxx, humidity:xxx, pressure:xxx}
```

Two issues:

1. What should  the Get URL be? (My first idea: `api/v1/WeatherByCityId/{cityid`) but it looks raw and untidy... or is it OK?
2. Do I need to create two entities: `City (table="cities")` and `Weather (table="weathers")` and create a relationship? OR better create one entity `WeathersCities(table="weathers_cities")` (or whatever...)?

(I'm not gonna use 3rd party weather services, please don't suggest RestTemplate, WebClient, FeignClient, etc. Yes, I will fill the weather data  by myself every hour.

Comment: Actually, the form of the URI isn't relevant to a client in a REST architecture, similar to the URI on a Web page should not convey meaning to a user either. Usually the accompanying data, such as link relation names that put the URI in relation to the current context or a human-readable text describing the content are more useful. The same holds true in a REST architecture. How you manage the data internally is up to you. Noone forces you to use a DB, you could also store it in a file or retrieve the data from an other service, hence this question will attract primarily opinionated answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you want to fetch the weather for a city, Lets store the city seperately in a `City` table and make `City Id` a primary key and put all the weather related data for the city in a seperate table `Weather` by keeping a foreign key City Id.

The RESTAPI would then be as such.

```sh
https://yourdomain.com/api/v1/city/{cityId}/weather
```

If your app's scope increases maybe later then you can reuse this same table principle and then the RESTAPI would be

```sh
https://yourdomain.com/api/v1/city/{cityId}?parameter=any_entity_you_have_mapped_with_city
```

> To summarize this, If your APP is just going to be about weather in the city then having a same table for both entities is okay. However, if you want that your APP can be used for querying a lot of other information about multiple entities like population, schools, etc then having a seperate table is a much better approach. I would recommend keeping seperate tables for the 2. This approach also makes the DB highly manageable. Let me know if you have some questions. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Don't you think: cities/{cityId}/weather is better?

Comment: You can use this one as well thats perfectly fine. However me personally like to breakdown a RESTFul API as follows for the city with this cityId give me the weather. You can use cities as well. I always prefer Plural form for entities when I want to fetch all the data for that entity.

Answer (score 1):

A One to Many mapping of City with Weathers is preferred.
Your weather table will have city_id as a foreign key for mapping.

The URL you suggested is a good way to go and will be easier to maintain if you're going for GET Mapping.

```
api/v1/weather/{cityid}
```

It will be more flexible to use so.

Comment: I thought about this approach, what confused me is: api/v1/weather/1 - nothing  indicates here the id = 1 is for city, not for weather, do you think is it well approach?

Comment: Yes, if GET mapping is Mandatory in your case, **cities/{city_id}/weather** seems to be a better idea.